# JButtons need to modify 8 JTextFields using an Array. Listen to Buttons or Text?

Tags: java, arrays, jbutton, jtextfield

This is homework, and this questions Extends [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386782/jbutton-needs-to-change-jtextfield-text)

So there is a button for `First`, `Prev`, `Next`, and `Last`

Each should modify

```
Item ID, Name, Rating, Price, Units, Value, Fee, ValueW/Fee, Total Inventory Value
```

The last one is a static total of all units.

I am not sure if I should make each button do multiple calls like this.

```
productName.setText( product.getProductName() );
itemNumber.setText( String.valueOf( product.getItemNumber() ) );
```

Or make each JTextArea listen for the button then change its field. Does that even work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Register an ActionListener for each button. In the body of that ActionListener's actionPerformed method, get the item to display and pass it to a method that will be responsible for setting the values to the text fields.

Something like:

```
JButton button = new JButton("Next");
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        DVDObject obj = getNextDVD();
        populateFields(obj);
    }
});

...

private DVDObject getNextDVD() {
    // gets the next object to display
    // you could call this method for each of the buttons, 
    // passing in an argument that determines which Object
    // to return (first, last, next, previous, whatever)
}

private void populateFields(DVDObject dvd) {
    // write out the values from the object passed in to the
    // fields
}
```

I'm guessing you've got some kind of collection of objects that contain all the information about DVDs, I've taken a stab in the dark and called it "DVDObject" here.

Comment: OK like this?= 
Button (Actionlistener( 
currentDisplay++
setTextFields(currentDisplay==))

setTextFields(int display)
fields[0].setText(inv.get(currentDisplay).getItem());
fields[1].setText(inv.get(currentDisplay).getName());
etc..

Comment: Yeah I think I can work with that. I like the approach thanks!

Comment: You've got to be joking. I gave you the answer in your last poting. Why are you wasting everybodys time asking the question over again.