# How to clear the JTextField by clicking JButton

Tags: java, swing, reset, jbutton, jtextfield

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [JButton needs to change JTextfield text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386782/jbutton-needs-to-change-jtextfield-text)

How do I clear a `JTextField` when a `JButton` is clicked?

Comment: Look at answer to the question linked in the previous comment. You can clear the text by setting the text to an empty string.

Answer (score 32):

Looking for [EventHandling](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), [ActionListener](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html)?

or code?

```
JButton b = new JButton("Clear");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        textfield.setText("");
        //textfield.setText(null); //or use this
    }
});
```

*Also See*
[How to Use Buttons](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)