# How to customize text field on Java (NetBeans)?

Tags: java, netbeans, text, jtextfield, currency

I want to create a text field with this default text: R$0,00. Then, when user types the numbers, it automatically formats the field, like:

R$0,00

User presses 1: R$0,01

User presses 5: R$0,15

User presses 7: R$1,57

User presses 0: R$15,70

And, if the user delete something, only numbers will disappear. Any sugestion?

Thanks !

Comment: you can develop your logic using JavaScript's `onKeyPress()` function!

Comment: `http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/` please look at this jquery plugin

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to clear the JTextField by clicking JButton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5328945/how-to-clear-the-jtextfield-by-clicking-jbutton)

Comment: Solved using FormatEditor, category 'mask' and some fixes with keyevents. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just have to write if statements and just setText of that text field and in the delete case just setText="" ..

Hope it helps

Comment: Solved using FormatEditor, category 'mask' and some fixes with keyevents. Thanks !