# How do I insert values into a JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield

In my program, I am making use of buttons and a slider to determine the tax and tip of an order from a restaurant. For the tax, I can choose a few states such as Arizona and their tax rate which is 5.6%. For the tip, I am to use the slider to allow the user to choose how much they want to tip. However, I need the information to display in my `JTextField` components while having them be un-editable.

Here is how the GUI looks:

[image]

Any tips?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386782/jbutton-needs-to-change-jtextfield-text

Comment: [How to Use Sliders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)